# R optim() L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn' - Weibull

Tags: r, weibull

I try to estimate the three parameters a, b0 and b1 with the `optim()` function. But I always get the error: 
Error in optim(par = c(1, 1, 1), fn = logweibull, method = "L-BFGS-B",  : 
L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn'

```
t<-c(6,6,6,6,7,9,10,10,11,13,16,17,19,20,22,23,25,32,32,34,35,1,1,2,2,3,4,4,5,5,8,8,8,8,11,11,12,12,15,17,22,23)
d<-c(0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
X<-c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

logweibull <- function (a,b0,b1) {a <- v[1];b0 <- v[2]; b1 <- v[3];
sum (d*log(t^a*exp(b0+X*b1)-t^a*exp(b0+X*b1))) + sum (d + log((a*t^(a-1))/t^a)) }

v<-c(1,1,1)

optim( par=c(1,1,1) ,fn = logweibull, method = "L-BFGS-B",lower = c(0.1, 0.1,0.1), upper = c(100, 100,100),control = list(fnscale = -1) )
```

Can you help me? Do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: `logweibull <- function (a,b0,b1) {a <- v[1];b0 <- v[2]; b1 <- v[3] ;sum (d*log(t^a*exp(b0+X*b1))-t^a*exp(b0+X*b1)) + sum (d * log((a*t^(a-1))/t^a)) }`        Thanks there was a mistake and some brackets missing. But now the function is still not working right. I will get just the starting values back as estimated parameters. Do you have an idea what is wrong there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may also consider

(1) passing the additional data variables to the objective function along with the parameters you want to estimate.

(2) passing the gradient function (added the gradient function)

(3) the original objective function can be further simplified (as below)

```
logweibull <- function (v,t,d,X) {
  a <- v[1] 
  b0 <- v[2] 
  b1 <- v[3] 
  sum(d*(1+a*log(t)+b0+X*b1) - t^a*exp(b0+X*b1) + log(a/t)) # simplified function
}

grad.logweibull <- function (v,t,d,X) {
  a <- v[1] 
  b0 <- v[2] 
  b1 <- v[3] 
  c(sum(d*log(t) - t^a*log(t)*exp(b0+X*b1) + 1/a), 
    sum(d-t^a*exp(b0+X*b1)),
    sum(d*X - t^a*X*exp(b0+X*b1)))
}

optim(par=c(1,1,1), fn = logweibull, gr = grad.logweibull,
      method = "L-BFGS-B",
      lower = c(0.1, 0.1,0.1), 
      upper = c(100, 100,100),
      control = list(fnscale = -1), 
      t=t, d=d, X=X)
```

with output

```
$par
[1] 0.2604334 0.1000000 0.1000000

$value
[1] -191.5938

$counts
function gradient 
      10       10 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
[1] "CONVERGENCE: REL_REDUCTION_OF_F <= FACTR*EPSMCH"
```

Also, below is a comparison between the convergence of with and without gradient function (with finite difference). With an explicit gradient function it takes 9 iterations to converge to the solution, whereas without it (with finite difference), it takes 126 iterations to converge.

[image]

Comment: But ideally should not conditional expectation be computed using the condtional pdf? take a look at this: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12843/generating-random-samples-from-a-custom-distribution, how they are sampling from an arbitrary pdf (by computing the cdf and then finding roots), should not the monte carlo sampling be done from this truncated pdf?