# Supply mle with gradients in R

Tags: r, gradient, derivative, estimation, mle

My goal is to supply gradients of my objective log(density) function to mle(), as this apparently speeds up the convergence process and makes it more stable (according to https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282009/defining-gradient-function-argument-in-optim-function-r).

My simplified LL, a bit of data and the standard mle are as follows:

```
library(stats4)
LL <- function(n,s)
{
  V = (u(z1,n)-u(z2,n))*p + u(z2,n) 
  res = zce - u.inv(V,n)
  ll = dnorm(x=res, mean=0, sd=s,log=T)
  return(-sum(ll))
}

### Functions:
u <- function(x,n) 
{
  ifelse(n!=1, util <- x^(1-n)/(1-n), util <- log(x))
  return(util)
}
u.inv <- function(x,n)
{
  ifelse(n !=1, inv.util <- ((1-n)*(x))^(1/(1-n)), inv.util <- exp(x))
  return(inv.util)
}

### Data 
z1 <- c(0.1111111, 0.1037037, 0.1222222, 0.1111111, 0.1074074, 0.1666667, 0.1333333, 0.2000000, 0.1333333, 0.1074074,
        0.1037037, 0.1111111, 0.1333333, 0.2000000, 0.1222222, 0.1111111, 0.1666667, 0.1333333, 0.1111111, 0.1333333,
        0.1111111, 0.1666667, 0.1074074, 0.1333333, 0.1222222, 0.2000000, 0.1037037)

z2 <- c(0.08888889, 0.06666667, 0.07777778, 0.00000000, 0.03333333, 0.09259259, 0.09629630, 0.08888889, 0.06666667,
        0.03333333, 0.06666667, 0.08888889, 0.06666667, 0.08888889, 0.07777778, 0.00000000, 0.09259259, 0.09629630,
        0.00000000, 0.09629630, 0.08888889, 0.09259259, 0.03333333, 0.06666667, 0.07777778, 0.08888889, 0.06666667)

p <-  c(0.5, 0.9, 0.5, 0.9, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.9, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.9, 0.1, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.9, 0.5, 0.5, 0.1, 0.9)

zce <- c(0.11055556, 0.10277778, 0.11000000, 0.10833333, 0.10185185, 0.11666667, 0.13240741, 0.14166667, 0.13166667,
         0.07222222, 0.08796296, 0.09944444, 0.09500000,0.10833333, 0.09444444, 0.05277778, 0.10925926, 0.11759259,
         0.05833333, 0.10277778, 0.09277778, 0.10925926, 0.06111111, 0.08833333, 0.09222222, 0.12500000, 0.09166667)

### mle()
fit <- mle(LL,
           start = list(n = 0.1,s=0.1),
           method = "L-BFGS-B",
           lower = list(n=-Inf,s=0.0001),
           upper = list(n=0.9999,s=Inf),
           control = list(maxit = 500, ndeps = rep(0.000001,2),trace= 6),
           nobs=length(z1))
```

What I have learned from the next link is that I should 1) calculate the partial derivates of my log(density) function with respect to each parameter that I estimate, and put them into an additional "gradient" function which I then supply to mle() with argument "gr": [R optim() L-BFGS-B needs finite values of 'fn' - Weibull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39747569/r-optim-l-bfgs-b-needs-finite-values-of-fn-weibull).

```
### Simplify log(dnorm)
# log(dnorm) = log((1/(s*sqrt(2*pi)))*exp(-((res-mu)^2/(2*s^2))))
# log(dnorm) = log((1/(s*sqrt(2*pi)))) - (res-mu)^2/(2*s^2)
# mu = 0
# log(dnorm) = log(1/s) + log(1/sqrt(2*pi)) - res^2/(2*s^2)

### Derivative of log(dnorm), that is, -res^2/(2*s^2) with respect to n
# = -1/(2*s^2)*2*res*dres/dn 

## Derivatives of u(x,n) and u.inv(x,n) with respect to n
d.u.n <- function(x,n){ifelse(n!=1, d.util <- x^(-n), d.util <- 1/x); return(d.util)}
d.u.inv.n <- function(x,n){ifelse(n!=1, d.inv.util <- x^(1/(1-n)-1), d.inv.util <- exp(x)); return(d.inv.util)}

## Derivative of res with respect to n: 
# dres/dn = d(zce - u.inv(V,n) )/dn
# dres/dn = -d.u.inv.n(V,n)*( (d.u.n(z1,n)-d.u.n(z2,n))*p + d.u.n(z2,n))

# Derivative of -res^2/(2*s^2) with respect to n
# dres/dn = -1/(2*s^2)*2*res*-d.u.inv.n(V,n)*( (d.u.n(z1,n)-d.u.n(z2,n))*p + d.u.n(z2,n))

# Derivative of log(dnorm) with respect to s:
# log(dnorm) = log(1/s) + log(1/sqrt(2*pi)) - res^2/(2*s^2)
# d(log(dnorm))/ds = s*-s^(-2) - res^2/2*s^(-3)*(-2)
# d(log(dnorm))/ds = -1/s + res^2*s^(-3)

### adopting the method from the link
pars <- c(1,1)
LL.gr <- function(pars, zz1=z1,zz2=z2,pp=p,zcee=zce)
{
  nn <- pars[1]
  sig <- pars[2]
  V = (u(z1,nn)-u(z2,nn))*pp + u(zz2,nn) 
  res = zcee - u.inv(V,nn)

  c(sum(-1/(2*sig^2)*2*res*-d.u.inv.n(V,nn)*( (d.u.n(zz1,nn)-d.u.n(zz2,nn))*pp + d.u.n(zz2,nn))),
    sum(-1/sig + res^2*sig^(-3))
  )
}

### mle() with gradient
fit <- mle(LL,
           start = list(n = 0.1,s=0.1),
           method = "L-BFGS-B",
           lower = list(n=-Inf,s=0.001),
           upper = list(n=0.9999,s=Inf),
           control = list(maxit = 500, ndeps = rep(0.000001,2),trace= 6),
           nobs=length(z1),
           gr = LL.gr)
```

Running this produces an error:

```
N = 2, M = 5 machine precision = 2.22045e-16
L = -inf 0.001 
X0 = 0.1 0.1 
U = 0.9999 inf 
At X0, 0 variables are exactly at the bounds
At iterate     0  f=      -36.749  |proj g|=       257.81
Iteration     0

---------------- CAUCHY entered-------------------

There are 0  breakpoints

GCP found in this segment
Piece      1 f1, f2 at start point         nan         nan
Distance to the stationary point =          nan
Cauchy X =  nan nan 

---------------- exit CAUCHY----------------------

2  variables are free at GCP on iteration 1
Error in optim(start, f, method = method, hessian = TRUE, ...) : 
  non-finite value supplied by optim
```

Thanks for helping out!

**UPDATE 1**

I believe now that the way I pass the gradient is indeed the correct way of supplying the gradient to mle(), which answers the main question of my post.

What I still not quite understand is how to pass the latent parameter values, that is, the parameter values at any iteration during the optimisation procedure, to the gradient function. I thought about putting the latent parameter values in a variable "par" in order to pass them on to the gradient function:

```
LL <- function(n,s)
{
  V = (u(z1,n)-u(z2,n))*p + u(z2,n) 
  res = zce - u.inv(V,n)
  ll = dnorm(x=res, mean=0, sd=s,log=T)
  par <- c(n,s)
  return(-sum(ll))
}

LL.gr <- function(par, zz1=z1 ,zz2=z2,pp=p,zcee=zce)
{
  n <- par[1]
  s <- par[2]
  V = (u(zz1,n)-u(zz2,n))*pp + u(zz2,n) 
  res = zcee - u.inv(V,n)
  print(s)
  c(sum(-1/(2*s^2)*2*res*-d.u.inv.n(V,n)*( (d.u.n(zz1,n)-d.u.n(zz2,n))*pp + d.u.n(zz2,n))),
    sum(-1/s + res^2*s^(-3))
  )
}
```

If I slightly cheat to solve the issue that produced the "nan", which result from `d.u.n(zz2,n)` being infinity for the z2 = zz2 values that equal 0, then the process does converge, but (strangely?) it does so towards the start values I set for n and s, thus 0.1 in the example.

```
z2 <- c(0.08888889, 0.06666667, 0.07777778, 0.0001, 0.03333333, 0.09259259, 0.09629630, 0.08888889, 0.06666667,
            0.03333333, 0.06666667, 0.08888889, 0.06666667, 0.08888889, 0.07777778, 0.0001, 0.09259259, 0.09629630,
            0.0001, 0.09629630, 0.08888889, 0.09259259, 0.03333333, 0.06666667, 0.07777778, 0.08888889, 0.06666667)

mle(LL,
           start = list(n = 0.1,s=0.1),
           method = "L-BFGS-B",
           lower = list(n=-Inf,s=0.001),
           upper = list(n=0.9999,s=Inf),
           control = list(maxit = 500, ndeps = rep(0.0001,2),trace= 6),
           nobs=length(z1),
           gr = LL.gr)

mle(minuslogl = LL, start = list(n = 0.1, s = 0.1), method = "L-BFGS-B", 
    nobs = length(z1), lower = list(n = -Inf, s = 0.001), upper = list(n = 0.9999, 
        s = Inf), control = list(maxit = 500, ndeps = rep(1e-04, 
        2), trace = 6), gr = LL.gr)

Coefficients:
  n   s 
0.1 0.1
```

Does anyone have clue why I get the start values out? Is my way of passing the latent variables correct? Thanks again.

Comment: In ll.gr are both n and s supposed to be pulling from pars[1]?

Comment: nope, edited it, thanks. In all honesty, I do not get this way of supplying pars, I find it quite unintuitive (which is one reason why I prefer mle to optim). For this post I just copy pasted the technique from the link.